# Obtaining linear relaxation objective value from MILP model coded in Pyomo

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, cplex, pyomo, lp-relaxation

I would like to seek some advice on modeling the following:

I am currently using Pyomo to generate my MILP model in Pyomo. It seems that it is not possible to cast the integer and binary variables to continuous variables for solving the model as a linear program for obtaining its linear relaxation.

Short of creating a similar model for linear relaxation due to model loading and solution time constraints, I would like to ask if there is any way to invoke the solver from Pyomo to solve the said model as a Linear Program?

Answer (score 2):

Can't you add a parameter to your model which defines the nature of your variables ?

Something like :

```
def my_model(model, continuous):

   ...

   if continuous:
      model.my_variable = Var(within=NonNegativeReals)
   else:
      model.my_variable = Var(within=PositiveIntegers)

   ...
```

and then `model.solve()`.

---

I am not so familiar with Pyomo but with [PuLP](https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/index.html), depending on the solver that you are using, [you can add a parameter `mip=True/False`](https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/technical/solvers.html) which should do the trick. Perhaps it is possible to do the same with Pyomo ? In this case you wouldn't have to rebuild the model.

Comment: Hi, I thought of doing so, but that would entail rebuilding up the model again after obtaining the linear relaxation, which would result in time overheads. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I am afraid not, cos I am unable to locate any literature that mentions anything along this line of thought. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure ?https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/working_abstractmodels/pyomo_command.html

Comment: Hi, I do not see any mention of linear relaxation, or anything with regards to passing a flag to the solver to indicate the use of it. Thanks

Comment: Try pyomo solve --solver=cplex --solver-options="mip=False"

Comment: Hi, I am afraid CPLEX does not recognize it. THanks

Comment: What error is raised ?

Comment: Hi, it is "MIP parameter 'false' does not exist"

Comment: Try something like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56812526/setting-optimalitytarget-parameter-in-python-for-cplex-solver-pyomo): solver = SolverFactory('cplex')
solver.options['mip'] = False

Comment: Hi, that's what I tried previously.